# Php : Send a byte string via UDP

Tags: php, string, udp, byte

My goal : **send an UDP broacast message in php . The message must be a string of byte.**

This is my test code

```
const TIMEOUT = 5;
const PORT = 8888;
const IP = "255.255.255.255";
const STR = "test";

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP); 
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1);
socket_set_option($sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,array("sec"=>TIMEOUT,"usec"=>0));
socket_sendto($sock, STR, strlen(STR), 0, IP, PORT);

//wait the responses for TIMEOUT sec
while(true) {
    $ret = @socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 20, 0, $ipDevice, $portDevice);
    if($ret === false) break;
        echo "-".$buf." - ".$ipDevice.":".$portDevice . "<br>";
}
socket_close($sock);
```

But **socket_sendto** require a string parameter to send (my STR variable).

So the question is : **How can i convert a string (my STR variable) to a string of bytes** ?

Comment: I'm honestly confused as to what you're trying to ask for here

Comment: @Blake question update...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can make an UDP broadcast:

```
<?php
$broadcast_string = "test";
$port = 1234;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1);
socket_sendto($sock, $broadcast_string, strlen($broadcast_string), 0, '255.255.255.255', $port);
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

**EDIT:**
Here is how to convert `string` into string of bytes:

```
$byte_array = unpack('C*', 'The quick fox jumped over the lazy brown dog');
var_dump($byte_array);  // $byte_array should be int[] which can be converted
                        // to byte[] since values are range of 0 - 255
```

Comment: ok ... but this is not the problem.  I already know how to send a broadcast message via udp (in fact the code works)....

Comment: Then what is the problem?